# Hat icons occasionally change

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2017

Sometimes I see on the [WinterBash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) that the icons for hats occasionally change:

> [image: same icons]

Refreshing the page fix the issue:

> [image: normal icons]

This probably happens if you open the page before earning the hat and then switch to the tab after the earning.

Comment: That's a browser bug. What browser are you using?

Comment: @balpha pictures were taken from the Chrome on iPad. I hope you won't say to me that mobile browser is not supported :)